# When updating unpredictable columns out of many, how to keep the other columns with their current values?

Tags: python, sqlite

Using Python and the built-in Sqlite: 
When I use a prepared statement, not knowing what columns the user will want to update:

```
UPDATE_AUTHOR = """UPDATE lastName=?, firstName=?, age=?, nationality=? FROM authors
        WHERE _id = ?
        """
```

How can I replace the '?' with some value that will keep the current value for some of the columns? 
From the user perspective, I will tell him for example to press 'Enter' if he wishes to keep the current value. So for instance, he presses 'Enter' on lastName, updates firstName, updates age, and presses 'Enter' on nationality. And I replace his 'Enter' with, hopefully, a value that will keep the current value.

Is that possible? If not, how can I solve this problem differently but efficiently? 
I thought about building the prepared statement dynamically, in the above example: adding `firstName=?,` and  `age=?,` after `"UPDATE`, and then the rest of the statement `FROM authors WHERE _id = ?"`. But this seems less comfortable and less organized.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of handling this question. One is to build a specific UPDATE query containing only the fields that will change. As you have said it is less comfortable because the query and the parameter list have to be tweaked.

Another way it to consistently update all the parameters, but keep the saved values for those which should not change. This is a common design in user interfaces:

- the user is presented all the values for an object and can change some of them
- if they confirm their choice, the application retrieves all the values, either changed or not and uses them in an UPDATE query.

Anyway, it is common the read the all the values before changing some, so it is not necessarily expensive. And at the database level, changing one or more values in an update has generally almost the same cost: a record is loaded from disk (or cache), some values are updated which is the cheapest operation, and it is then written back to disk. Even with the database caches, the most expensive part in the databases I know is to load and save the record.

Comment: If I understood correctly, and please correct me, you are suggesting to query *all the columns* for an object, save them as temporary values until the user completes the process, and then update each column whether the user changed them or not. 
This seems very inefficient, is it not? You wrote yourself, loading is the most expensive at the database level, so why load all the columns? In that case, building a specific UPDATE statement seems to be much faster, since I only add strings to the statement, without loading any columns initially.

Comment: @Kronecker: at an underlying level, the database processes *records*. BTW I am not suggesting to load and change *all the columns* but *all the columns **that could be changed***

Comment: Whether what columns could be changed or not, can vary on the database and its purpose. But you are still suggesting to load many columns, when in fact, I have a solution that doesn't load, but updates and saves. What if my database have 100 columns? What if I have hundreds of thousands users? Sure, I won't change _id and some other arbitrary columns. But loading so many columns for the sole purpose of a "default" value, from my perspective, is pure inefficiency.

Comment: @Kronecker: IMHO there is no definitive answer: it depends on the way you update. If you use a human interface, you will probably not present 100 values to the user in one single screen...